# How can I append an underscore to a string variable in PowerShell without it interpreting a carriage return in a .ps1 file?

Tags: powershell

How can I append a - or _ to a string variable in PowerShell it interpreting a carriage return inside a script file?

I would like the _* appended to the end of my $curUserID variable, so that I can then use this as a filter.

I have tried lots of ways to get this, but all of them result in a carriage return after my curUserID value when inside of a script file. It works fine when I do the same at a command line in PowerShell?!

Here is my code:

```
$curUserID = "28";
$filePrefix = "${curUserID}$('_*')";
```

when I run this from inside of a script file, I get the following

```
28
_*
```

But what I need is the following, which is what I get when I run the above at the command line.

```
28_*
```

Comment: I miss something, I cant reproduce your problem

Answer (score 12):

```
$filePrefix = "${curUserID}_*"
```